# Using sum of squares regression for fitting a sinusoid

Tags: trigonometry, regression

I am trying to use the least squares regression to fit a curve to a table of values representing a sine wave. Similar to the question:
[Least squares regression of sine wave](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3926007/least-squares-regression-of-sine-wave)

Except I want to fit a more general formula of: $a * \sin(b*x + c) + d$

So given a function table I want to get the coefficients $a, b, c, d$ that most resemble the table given. Later I want to turn this into a computer program so I want to automatize all of the logic.

The regression formula (if that's the way to name it) I used: $Minimize(\sum_{i=1}^n (a* \sin(bx_i + c) + d - y_i)^2)$

Based on this I got these two formulas for $a$ and $d$:
The sums here iterate over the elements in the function table.

$z_i = \sin(bx_i + c)$

$a = \frac{n\sum y_i z_i - (\sum y_i) * (\sum z_i)}{n\sum (z_i^2) - (\sum z_i)^2}$

$d = \frac{(\sum y_i) * (\sum z_i)^2 - (\sum z_i) * (\sum y_i * z_i)}{n \sum (z_i^2) - (\sum z_i)^2}$

I defined $b$ by the period (named $p$) which I will learn to calculate later:

$b = \frac{2\pi}{p}$

What I am now stuck at is the phase shift $c$. Which if I calculate in a similar fashion as $a$ and $b$ is stuck in this horrible formula:
$0 = \sum (\cos(bx_i + c) * a * z_i + d * \cos(bx_i + c) - y_i * \cos(bx_i + c))$

This later turns into

$2\sum y_i*\cos(bx_i + c) = a*cos(2c)\sum \sin(2bx_i) + a*\sin(2c)*\sum \cos(2bx_i) + 4d*cos(c) \sum \cos(bx_i)$

If I use the regression formula: $Minimize(\sum(\sin^{-1}(\frac{y_i - d}{a})-bx_i - c)^2)$

I get
$c = \frac{\sum \frac{\arcsin(\frac{y_i - d}{a}) - bx_i}{\sqrt{a^2 - (d - y_i)^2}}}
{\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 - (d - y_i)^2}}}
$

Is there any way to define $c$ from this last equation and simplify the above mentioned equations?

Demo of the problem: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iyacah4ors

Comment: I miss $y_i$ in your _ansatz_ $Minimize(\sum_{i=1}^n (a* sin(bx + c) + d)^2)$

Comment: You are right sorry for that

Comment: How about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301194)?

Comment: Well the first answer just chooses a different way. In the second answer, in which he mentions what I am trying to do, he says: "Of course, inverse trig functions like to behave badly, so this might not work.". Which I am confused by.